# Dovecot - Remove read email

Tags: email-server, dovecot, imap, pop3

Is there a way to automatically remove mail after it is read within dovecot either through a configuration or plugin?

I'm running the following two packages:

```
dovecot-core                     1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2     
dovecot-pop3d                    1:2.0.19-0ubuntu2
```

If I can't remove it automatically, is there perhaps another way for moving read mail to another location automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have dovecot v2, you are able to use `doveadm` utility that can do a lot of funny things with letters.
Just add to the crontab the next command:

```
30 3 * * * root /path/to/the/doveadm expunge -A SEEN 2> /dev/null
```

and all the seen messages will be deleted at 03:30am every day. Redirection of stderr needed because doveadm shows brief report each time and cron will send it by email to the root.